# Push mysql json in array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, json

I have a problem with a mysql query in nodeJs.
In practice I do the query and it returns a json to me with the result of the query, I then have to insert the result returned by the query in a variable that is an array. I just don't know how to scroll and select the elements of the arrays as it always gives me undefined when I try to select an element such as 'name'.

Mysql query:

```
conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?",[id] ,function(err, result){
        if(!err){
          if(result.length == 1){
            //Invio segnale di logged-in al client
            conn.end();
            resolve(result[0]);
          }
        }
      })
```

Code node:

```
socket.on('index', function(){
  socket.emit('index', counterOnline);
  if(counterOnline > 0){
    console.log(userOnline);
    socket.emit('userOnline', userOnline);
  }
})
```

Log:

```
[ Promise { RowDataPacket { id: 2, nome: 'matteo', cognome: 'busacca', mail: 'mbusacca98@gmail.com', username: 'mbusacca', password: '9827c06ddb1fb8a6f62555829bda33dd', city: '', instagram: '', linkedin: '', facebook: '', photo: '/fotoUtenti/2.jpg' } } ]
```

If I do, console.log (userOnline[0].nome); I get 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resolve(result[0])` will return a promise and you have to use :

```
var userOnline = [];
socket.on('online', function(idUser){
  counterOnline++;
   dataUser.online(idUser).then(function(idUser) {
     userOnline.push(idUser);
   })

})
```

Comment: I get the same 'undefined', can you give me an example of what you say with written code?

Comment: Please Share the function definition of counterOnline and userOnline

Comment: But userOnline and counterOnline are two variables, respectively an array and a normal variable.

Comment: Where are you assigning them? How you are calling the piece of code that has `conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?",[id] ,function(err, result){`?

Comment: Thank you very much very kind. Another question, now to delete a record by ID from the array what can I do?

Comment: `var index = userOnline.indexOf(Id goes here);
 
    if (index > -1) {
       userOnline.splice(index, 1);
    }`

If the answer was helful, please upvote and accept. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
var userOnline = [];
socket.on('online', function(idUser){
  counterOnline++;
  userOnline.push(dataUser.online(idUser));
})
```

dataUser.online(idUser) :

```
function online(id){

var response = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

var conn = connect();

  conn.connect(function(err){
    if(!err){
      //query ricerca utente nel db
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?",[id] ,function(err, result){
        if(!err){
          if(result.length == 1){
            //Invio segnale di logged-in al client
            conn.end();
            resolve(result[0]);
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })

  })

  return response;
   }
```